# Auto Refresh Form in Access 2017

Tags: ms-access

Is there a way to auto refresh a form by time?  I'm creating an status board to display the current RMA status on a big screen for manufacturing.  Is there a way to refresh this data every 10 seconds or so?    Thanks in advance for any assistance.  Tony

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. Just set the Timer interval property on the form, and use the Form_Timer event.

Add the following code to auto-refresh on the timer.

```
Private Sub Form_Timer()
    Me.Requery
End Sub
```

Note that the timer interval is in milliseconds, so 10 seconds = 10000.
Also note that it causes a noticable "blink", and can reset the field you're currently focusing on.

Comment: 10000. :) `Application.Echo False / True` helps with the blinking.