# How can I force MS-Access to automatically refresh a record which was modified by a trigger with an external, non-MSAccess DB backend?

Tags: ms-access, odbc

I'm using MS-Access (MS-365) as a front-end to a backend Postgres table served on linux through ODBC.
I've written a pre-update trigger in the Postgres DB table to change the value of a field. For example, increment an integer that was modified in an integer field of a record in MS-Access.  It seems to work fine except that the new value is not automatically updated in the MS-Access table until/unless I click the "refresh" button. Is there a way I to force an automatic refresh of the modified record in the MS-Access view after it is written to the backend DB ?   It seemed to do this automatically when the backend was MS-Access.

Thanks for any help !

Comment: Access should automatically refresh on a set interval - is that not happening?. If this is not adequate, then need to somehow run code to do refresh, however, I am not sure how that can be done since there is no event involved on the Access side.

Comment: I read something about refreshing a refresh interval, but can't seem to find how to set that in Access.  Is there w way to set the interval ?  And is there a way to instruct to refresh/reset only the record(s) that were changed on the frontend side ?

Comment: Refresh interval is an Access application-wide client setting, not a database setting: File > Options > Client Settings > Advanced > Refresh Interval. Default appears to be 1 minute. Can set a form timer to refresh more frequently but I understand this is a memory hog https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45547939/auto-refresh-form-in-access-2017. But how frequently is enough? Still would be some delay after the PostGres trigger. No, don't know any way to refresh only changed records.

Answer (score 0):

> I did (eventually) find the refresh interval settings. They can be
> found by clicking
>
> File -> Options -> Client Settings
>
> and then scrolling down to "Advanced"
>
> then selecting 0 for the refresh interval and obdb refresh interval.

You are on the track, but **0** here means "never".

So, leave the *refresh retry interval* at 250ms and set the *ODBC refresh interval* to, say, 5s.

That works here.